# Why were Adam and Hava punished?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, parashat-bereishit, adam, morality

Since Adam and Hava didn't know what was right and wrong until after they ate from the Tree of Knowledge of Good and Evil, why were they punished for eating from it? They couldn't have known it was wrong.

Comment: why not,maybe the yetzer harah wasnt internal yet but eho said there wasnt an external yetzer harah

Comment: However they knew it was forbidden. Knowledge after eating is of a different type than before. They were not ignorant.

Comment: @sabbahillel Than what does "knowledge of good and evil mean"?

Comment: Rav Hirsch and other meforshim go into this. Also see the tape series by Rabbi David Fohrman and the transcripts at [Serpents of Desire: Good and Evil in the Garden of Eden. An Introduction](http://www.aish.com/jl/b/eb/ge/48966101.html)